# Refresh view on Ember Data update

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js, ember-data

I’m doing a very basic application with Ember and Ember Data.
For some reason I always have the same problem. My application renders and displays the data correctly, but if I remove and search, it doesn't update the view.

I’ve already asked this [here](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/refresh-content/5252/)—the link has more code examples—but with not much luck. Here [is how I’m trying to do it](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dolasuto/8/edit):

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true, LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS: true
});

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();
App.Sample = DS.Model.extend({ name: DS.attr('string') });


App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
      return this.store.find('sample');
   }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
    remove: function(sample) {
      sample.destroyRecord();
    }
  }
});


App.Sample.FIXTURES = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Learn Ember.js'},
  { id: 2, name: 'Record 2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Test Delete' }
];

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    showModal: function(name, content) {
      this.controllerFor(name).set('content', content);
      this.render(name, {
        into: 'application',
        outlet: 'modal'
      });
    },
    removeModal: function() {
      this.disconnectOutlet({
        outlet: 'modal',
        parentView: 'application'
      });
    }
  }
});

App.MyModalComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    ok: function() {
      this.$('.modal').modal('hide');
      this.sendAction('ok');
    }
  },
  show: function() {
    this.$('.modal').modal().on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
      this.sendAction('close');
    }.bind(this));
  }.on('didInsertElement')
});
```

Answer (score 3):

From your code I have tried to come up with a reasonable solution for your problem

Before I get into the solution I think the controller should be `IndexController` rather than `sampleDeleteModalController` because ember expects controller to have same name as the route.

```
App.SampleDeleteModalController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    remove: function() {
        // Two ways
        this.get('model').destroyRecord(); 
        this.transitionToRoute('index');
    }
  }
});
```

transitionToRoute from the same route will not refresh a view.This will work only when you want to redirect to another route.

Solution to refresh view

option 1 : you can capture the same action inside index route after removing the record you can do `this.refesh()` which refreshes the model.

option 2 : You have to explicitly update the binded model inside the controller.

```
actions: {
    remove: function() {
        // Two ways
        var localCopy = this.get('model');
        localCopy.destroyRecord(); 
        this.set('model',localCopy);
    }
  }
```

option 3 : After you set your model your model and then do this.rerender().Which is almost equivalent to `window.reload()`